# How to tell which bootstrap tab is selected in Angular-UI

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

Is there a way to tell which tab that has been selected when using the Bootstrap tabs in [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/)?

I tried watching the panes array but it deosn't seem to be updated when switching tab. Can one specify a callback function when a tab is selected?

Update with code example.

The code very much follows the example from the Angular UI bootstrap page.

Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
    <tabs>
        <pane ng-repeat="pane in panes" heading="{{pane.title}}" active="pane.active">
            <div ng-include="pane.template"></div>
        </pane>
    </tabs>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var TabsCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.panes = [
    { title:"Events list", template:"/path/to/template/events" },
    { title:"Calendar", template:"/path/to/template/calendar" }
  ];
};
```

Comment: would be awesome if you could check if my answer does the trick for you and if not, open an issue in https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap with a proposal on how you would like it to work!

Comment: You put me in the right direction. I wanted to run some code when a certain tab was selected and I came up with this solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/zctmee

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually this is really simple as each `pane` exposes the `active` attribute that supports 2-way data binding:

```
<tabs>
    <pane ng-repeat="pane in panes" heading="{{pane.title}}" active="pane.active">      
        {{pane.content}}
    </pane>
</tabs>
```

and then an active tab can be easily found, for example:

```
$scope.active = function() {
    return $scope.panes.filter(function(pane){
      return pane.active;
    })[0];
};
```

Here is a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/fEvOtL?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @pkozlowski.opensource. This helped alot. It should definitely be included in the examples/documentation on the Bootstrap tabs in Angular UI.

Comment: What about if you're manually setting your tab panes and not using a repeater?

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource Any idea how to get the active tab when not using repeater?

Comment: this does not work anymore for the latest angular-bootstrap (2.3.0)

Answer (score 13):

if you don't have a repeater, bind tabs (or spans) activity to an Array

```
 <tab active="tabActivity[0]">...</tab>
 <tab active="tabActivity[1]">...</tab>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.tabActivity=[false,false];
```

then you can get active tab with

```
$scope.tabActivity.indexOf(true)
```

Comment: If you want to only check if one tab is selected, bind the active property of the tab to a model property and then use this property to determine other behavior on the page.

Comment: For better readability you can use object instead of array and object props instead of indexes. For example, $activeTabs = {people : true, projects : false}, <ui-tab active="activeTabs.people"> and check smthng like ng-show="activeTabs.people"

Answer (score 12):

I solved it by adding one method (onTabSelect) on the controller and calling it from ng-click event of Tab.
Below solution worked for me please [see this in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/87iGFTgNW0731Z1H1b4G?p=preview)

```
function myTabController($scope) {
  $scope.onTabSelect = function(tabName) {
    $scope.selectedTabName = tabName;
    console.log("Changed tab to " + tabName);
  }


  <tabset>
    <tab ng-click="onTabSelect('A')">
      <tab-heading>
        A
      </tab-heading>
    </tab>
    <tab ng-click="onTabSelect('B')">
      <tab-heading>
        B
      </tab-heading>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

Answer (score 4):

My answer is for the case you place manually the tab and you are using the angular ui boostrap library, you could use the `select` attribute

```
<uib-tabset class="main-nav">
  <uib-tab select="showTab('a')">
    <uib-tab-heading>a</uib-tab-heading>
    <div class="tab-content"> <span>a</span></div>
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab select="showTab('b')">
    <uib-tab-heading>b</uib-tab-heading>
    <div class="tab-content"> <span>b</span></div>
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

in the `showTab` function passing in `select` attribute, you can check whether your tab is selected by their name like in my case.

The full example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tc9lZWIz6kjS2WqmITXW?p=preview) from angular ui, notice the `select`:

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works only for dynamic tabs.

For static tabs, you can set the `active` attribute of `uib-tabset` directive to a scope property, and compare it with the tab index to find the active tab.

For example, in the below code I'm doing so to set a  class on active tab header (I can use the `active` class added by ui.bootstrap and achieve the same result, I'm doing so as an example):

```js
angular.module('test', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css");
 .test {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test">
  <uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab index="0">
      <uib-tab-heading ng-class="{test:active==0}">Static title1</uib-tab-heading>Static content1
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1">
      <uib-tab-heading ng-class="{test:active==1}">Static title1</uib-tab-heading>Static content2</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2">
      <uib-tab-heading ng-class="{test:active==2}">Static title1</uib-tab-heading>Static content3</uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</div>
```