# Angularjs tab pane change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using a bootstrap tab pane using a angular.

I want to find that which tab is clicked.

**Here is a plunker link of my example.[click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DLUZPbFH4CeieJ0mrY9I?p=preview).**

This is the code

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
   
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0.js"></script>
     
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
    <tabs>
            <pane heading="Information">Information Tab</pane>
            <pane heading="activity">activity Tab</pane>
            <pane heading="History">History Tab</pane>
    </tabs>
    <hr> 
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Note: this code is not working in snippet.

I want to find a click event of all the tabs, without using `ng-click`event because there is already a click event `ng-click="select(pane)"`.

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tabs?

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu ,yes , but there is something different code.

Comment: duplicated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685360/how-to-tell-which-bootstrap-tab-is-selected-in-angular-ui

Comment: @VuQuyet, this is not a duplicate , they are calling a function for get the active tab , see the plunker